# MVC How to cache the results of an action to be used on multiple pages with OutputCache attribute

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, caching

We have an instance in our application where we would like to be able to cache the results of an MVC action for multiple pages with OutputCache but what I've just realized is my basic setup caches for each page individually and thus this breaks the chain.

My ultimate goal with this is when the user hits a main page to execute an ajax request once all others are finished that loads and caches the data for subsequent pages. Then when the user navigates to another page that needs the MVC actions data it is instantly available.

This is my script to load the data asynchronously on my main page,

```
$(document).one("ajaxStop", function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '../Companies/CompanySelectList',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            //alert(request.responseText);
        }
    })

})
```

And this is my MVC Action to be executed,

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60)]
public ActionResult CompanySelectList()
{
    List<CompanyDTO> companies = new List<CompanyDTO>();

    var results = _api.Companies.GetCompany();
    if (results.message == null)
    {
        companies.AddRange(results.data);

        //Build up remaining data
        for (int i = results.page + 1; i <= results.totalPages; i++)
        {
            results = _api.Companies.GetCompany(page: i);
            companies.AddRange(results.data);
        }

        companies = companies.OrderBy(n => n.CompanyName).ToList();
        return PartialView("_CompanySelectList", companies);
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", results.message);
    }

    return PartialView("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try directing the request to a web api controller, and building a simple manual caching mechanism in there.
An example can be found here: [Caching in Web API](http://sibeeshpassion.com/caching-in-web-api/)